# wxPython - Combobox with Checkboxes possible?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to create an Combobox with checkboxes with wxpython?

Like most webpages have filter options in a drop down list for products where you could choose which Brand (etc.) you want.

Comment: There's `wx.CheckListBox`

Comment: getting closer to what i need. Can i add that to an Combobox? Or Create any other drop down list with that?

Comment: A `combobox` is a list of strings. If you look at an amazon page the categories and the filters are seperate. I don't see how checkboxes in a drop down list would work, unless you have an image that you can share. Finally, there is always the option of a menu, which can have, text, images, check items and radio items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a ComboCtrl with a CheckListBox popup, or with a wx.ListCtrl plus 
CheckListCtrlMixin if you need more than one column.

Comment: Working fine except binding EVT_CHECKLISTBOX. Could you take a look in my newest post? Thank you!